# Prevent sun interference with optical trackball?

Tags: interference, trackball

I have a Logitech Trackman that recently began showing weird behavior: slow pointer, random pointer movements. As it turns out, it was due to a newfound exposure to sunlight. (Yay for windows!)
Any ideas how to prevent interference caused by the sunlight? (Other than putting a cardboard box around my hand, please.)

Comment: It's wired! Also, if I cast a shade upon the trackball by putting my hand or whatnot between it and the sun, the problems go away.

Comment: Might work, but I'm afraid my employer would frown upon such a solution.

Comment: No. I just kept cupping the ball with my other hand when the interference got too bad. :P
I don't work in that office anymore, so it's no longer an issue for me either.